# Trigger doesn't respect autocommit option?

Tags: mysql, triggers, innodb, mysql-5.6

MySQL triggers body doesn't respect `AUTOCOMMIT` option and always runs in transaction?

---

#### Real world scenario

I just have `AFTER UPDATE` trigger which sets up some counters (for example flag change will decrease counter for the old flag and increase it for the new one) and there are two servers with relatively high load changing flags all the time... And sometime it deadlocks :)

---

#### Testing set-up

I've set up these two tables:

```
test (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    data TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

test2 (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    val INT DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Insert some dummy data:

```
INSERT INTO test (data) VALUES (RAND());
INSERT INTO test2 (id, val) VALUES
    (1, 0),
    (2, 0);
```

Create trigger which simulates data calculation (is purposely long to give me time to run second query) and does dummy change to data in `test2` table:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `test_AUPD` AFTER UPDATE ON `test` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE test2
    SET val = val + 1
    WHERE id = 1;

    SELECT SLEEP(30) INTO @void;

    UPDATE test2
    SET val = val - 1
    WHERE id = 2;

END $$
```

Of course:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'autocommit';
-- autocommit, ON
```

---

#### Testing results

When I call:

```
UPDATE test SET data = RAND();
```

in both connections first connection takes 30 seconds to complete update, but the **second one takes around 55 seconds**.

---

#### Question

- Where is this behaviour documented (I've spent few hours digging around InnoDB transaction locking and so on, but no luck)? *I guess this is reasonable behaviour when replication is turned on.*
- What's the proper way of synchronizing triggers updating counters in the same table? **OR** How to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Good way of debugging this seems to be selecting locks and transaction infos from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`:

```
SELECT 
    PS.id AS conneciton_id, PS.HOST AS host, PS.INFO AS query_full, INNOLOCK.lock_id,
    INNOLOCK.lock_mode, INNOLOCK.lock_type, INNOLOCK.lock_table, INNOLOCK.lock_rec, 
    INNOTRX.trx_query, INNOTRX.trx_state, INNOTRX.trx_requested_lock_id
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCKS AS INNOLOCK
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX AS INNOTRX 
    ON INNOLOCK.lock_trx_id = INNOTRX.trx_id
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST AS PS ON PS.ID = INNOTRX.trx_mysql_thread_id;
```

Which will fetch you data like this:

```
+-----------------------++-------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| connection_id         || *****                         | *****                       |
| host                  || *****:*****                   | *****:*****                 |
| query_full            || UPDATE test SET data = RAND() | SELECT SLEEP(30) INTO @void |
| lock_id               || 1234567890:12345678:2:3       | 0124567890:01234567:1:2     |
| lock_mode             || X                             | X                           |
| lock_type             || RECORD                        | RECORD                      |
| lock_table            || `test`                        | `test`                      |
| lock_rec              || 2                             | 2                           |
| trx_query             || UPDATE test SET data = RAND() | SELECT SLEEP(30) INTO @void |
| trx_state             || LOCK WAIT                     | RUNNING                     |
| trx_requested_lock_id || 0124567890:01234567:1:2       |                             |
+-----------------------++-------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Which immediately tells you that query displayed in the first column is waiting for lock `0124567890:01234567:1:2` and transaction with lock `0124567890:01234567:1:2` is right now in `SELECT SLEEP(30)`.

Comment: The "lock wait" explains the 55 sec -- about 2 * 30 sec.  The second connection could not start until the first finished.

Comment: @RickJames I know that it waits, but I just can't find any documentation on that

Comment: Sorry, I can't point to a page.  Lock mode X (exclusive) blocks other access.  A deadlock is effectively a set of locks that cannot be resolved by simply waiting.

Comment: @RickJames thanks for the effort, but this is all documented... I'm looking explicitly for in-trigger behavior.